# Position toast to top-left corner of the screen

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-toast

I'm having trouble positioning a custom toast at top-left corner of the screen. For some reason, there's a gap and I'm guessing that gaps is reserved for statusbar. But I hide the statusbar though. 
[image: This is what it looks like :]

This is my custom toast class. You can see that I set the gravity to top-left.

```
class CustomToast : Toast
{
    public CustomToast(Context context)
       : base(context)
    {

    }

    public CustomToast(Context context, Activity activity, string message, string title/*, bool flag*/)
        : base(context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.LayoutInflater;

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.banner, null);

        TextView header = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCustomToastTitle);
        TextView body = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCustomToast);


        header.Text = title;
        body.Text = message;
        SetGravity(GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Left, 0, 0);
        Duration = ToastLength.Long;
        View = view;
    }
}
```

And this is my layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop ="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/notificationbackground"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCustomToastTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCustomToast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT : I set my app to full screen mode. This is my oncreate method

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        instance = this; // Push notification test code
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        RegisterWithGCM();
    }
```

UPDATE : I think the reason why it doesn't let me position toast in status bar area(even though my app is in fullscreen mode) is because toast is displayed regardless of whether my app is in foreground or background. When my app is in background, toast will cover the status bar which google may not want.

Comment: This is probably what it considers to be top left. :/

Comment: try to make your `activity` to `full screen`.

Comment: @usmanlqbal Yup it is already set to Full Screen. I updated my question with oncreate method